# F# ASP.NET Core project: EntryPointAttribute error

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

This is my ASP.NET Core Web API entry-point:

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

module Hosting =
    let BuildWebHost args =
        WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .Build()

module Program =
    let [<EntryPoint>] main args = Hosting.BuildWebHost(args).Run(); 0
```

This is from `Program.fs`, the final file in my project.

After months of smooth compilation, I am suddenly getting the following compilation failure:

> error FS0433: A function labeled with the 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file in the compilation sequence.

It is the last declaration in the last file -- any idea why this might suddenly start failing now?

Comment: I'd double-check that it's *still* the final file in your project; it's possible that something may have caused it to move in the .fsproj file. For example, if you're using VS Code + Ionide, you might have accidentally pressed `Ctrl+Shift+Up` at some point, which is the shortcut for "Move File Up". If you didn't have the F# project view open at the time, you might not have gotten any visual feedback when that happened. It's happened to me a time or two.

Comment: Not happening here. It's the user secrets.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the user secrets infrastructure injects a file as the last file in the assembly. It is fixed in the next release of F#: see https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/833.

There is a workaround here: https://medium.com/@dmytrol/making-asp-net-core-user-secrets-work-in-f-projects-9b04572d81f6, in which you can set your User Secrets ID in your codebase rather than in the project file.